# dbmail @reply_to

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

I don't think I'm going to have much joy with this question but I can't see anyone has asked for a while...

Is there a way around the one email address limitation for the @reply_to in dbmail?

I'm wanting to group on average have a dozen addresses at a time & the reason behind the requirement is that they link to an internal DMS.

Any help or suggestions would be great, I've tried a variable but no joy.

Cheers
Bob

Comment: Use a distro list? Then you can manage that in AD or what ever exchange / etc you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately wouldn't work as the addresses are variable each & everytime.

Comment: Well... you could set up a report on SSRS and use a data driven subscription, if you have reporting services.

Comment: Which would probably work, I don't have Enterprise available to me though.